# Python decorator prints "none"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

```
import random
import time

def timeit(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print ("{} took {} secs \n".format(func.__name__, time.time() - start))
    return wrapper


@timeit
def insort(l):
    """ Uses insetion sort for sorting list """

    for i in range(1, len(l)): 
        temp = l[i]
        j = i
        while j > 0 and l[j - 1] > temp:
            l[j] = l[j - 1]
            j -= 1
            l[j] = temp
    return l


@timeit
def bublesort(l):
    """ Uses insetion sort for sorting list """

    for i in range(len(l)-1, 0, -1):
        for j in range(i):
            if l[j] > l[j+1]:
                l[j], l[j+1] = l[j+1], l[j]
    return l


x =random.sample(range(2000), 1000) 
print (insort(x[:]))
print (bublesort(x[:]))
```

Above code outputs:

```
insort took 0.0629999637604 secs 

None
bublesort took 0.104000091553 secs 

None
```

Why it is printing none after every result and how can I prevent it?
Also  I am new to decorators so I would like to know if there is any better way for timing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wrapper, which replaces the original function, ignores the return value and returns `None`.

Make the following change:

```
def timeit(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print ("{} took {} secs \n".format(func.__name__, time.time() - start))
        return ret
    return wrapper
```

This will make your decorator work properly. If you want to avoid printing the return values, change

```
print (insort(x[:]))
print (bublesort(x[:]))
```

to just

```
insort(x[:])
bublesort(x[:])
```

In general, if you don't want to print something, don't pass it to `print`.

Comment: How to prevent it?

Comment: It also outputs the result of the function. I don't want the result, it should output only the time.

Comment: @AnshulRaman: If you don't want to print the return value, *why are you printing the return value*?

Answer (score 2):

> Why it is printing none after every result and how can I prevent it? Also I am new to decorators so I would like to know if there is any better way for timing my code.

It's printing the return value of wrapper (None) because of this:

```
print (insort(x[:]))
print (bublesort(x[:]))
```

You are telling the interpreter to print the return value of these functions. 
If you don't want to see `None` then you should just *call* the functions:

```
insort(x[:])
bublesort(x[:])
```